# How to type data into table rows in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Right now I am trying to use selenium ide to write code that makes sure web pages on a website work. On one particular page there is a table that has text boxes in each cell. You can add a row by clicking a button. What I want to do on this page is type data into the first two rows. I used selenium ide and recorded me typing in data. Then I tried to replay it. It worked fine until it came to the second row. The second row it could not write data to. The first row text boxes had targets of terms[] and defs[] . the second row looks the exact same but has targets of `//td[@id='autoDefinerTd']/textarea` and `//table[@id='termList']/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/textarea` . I am completely stumped on what to do to fix this and why they are different. If someone could help me I would be so grateful.
Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out you just do it the normal way. For some reason selenium was doing it a weird way.